# Export data from MySQL to Excel with UTF-8 encoding

Tags: php, mysql, excel, csv

I have a mysql row with `utf8_general_ci` collation, when I export it to csv, instead of correct utf-8 characters I get `Ć…ā€¦I` etc, how to make excel understand UTF-8 encoding here is my code:

```
$conn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'asdfggh') or die(mysql_error());
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8"); 
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8"); 
mysql_select_db('table_name', $conn) or die(mysql_error($conn));

$query = sprintf('SELECT * FROM sudraba_birzs');
$result = mysql_query($query, $conn) or die(mysql_error($conn));

header('Content-Encoding: UTF-8');
header('Content-type: text/csv; charset=UTF-8');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.date("d-m-Y_H:i") . '.csv'.'"'); 
echo "\xef\xbb\xbf";

$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
if ($row) {
    echocsv(array_keys($row));
}

while ($row) {
    echocsv($row);
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
}

function echocsv($fields)
{
    $separator = '';
    foreach ($fields as $field) {
        if (preg_match('/\\r|\\n|,|"/', $field)) {
            $field = '"' . str_replace('"', '""', $field) . '"';
        }
        echo $separator . $field;
        $separator = ',';
    }
    echo "\r\n";
}
```

How to export it to get all characters display correctly (make Excel understand utf-8) and to maintain table layout too(with rows and columns)

Comment: You can try setting a UTF-8 BOM header, but you might also look at writing a real Excel file (BIFF .xls or OfficeOpenXML .xlsx) which will eliminate such problems by providing Excel with a file in its native format

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are generating CSV, which is basically a plain text file. There's no way to specify encoding information in such kind of files. Most text editors implement (better or worse) encoding auto-detection. Excel doesn't. Excel will simply assume ANSI when you right-click on a CSV file. (You need to use the "Open" menu in order to be prompted about encoding.)

Your only option left (apart from switching to another output format) is converting data to ANSI, either with [mb_convert_encoding()](https://www.php.net/mb_convert_encoding) or with [iconv()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php). But now you have another problem: ANSI is not a real encoding, it basically means "whatever encoding is set in *my* Windows computer". You first have to find out the typical encoding most of your users have. That mostly depends on the country. For instance, many Western Europe countries use Win-1252.

Comment: Thanks for info. I ended up using phpexcel to create xls file - no probs there  http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Examples&referringTitle=Home

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem (common problem in databases with spanish language). I wrote this and it worked:

This is a Class that connects with the database and the functions will do whatever you want using mysqli and PHP. In this case, calling this class (require or include), just use the "downloadCsv()" function.

As an example, this would be the "class.php" file:

```
<?php
class DB{

private $con;

//this constructor connects with the database
public function __construct(){
$this->con = new mysqli("Your_Host","Your_User","Your_Pass","Your_DatabaseName");

if($this->con->connect_errno > 0){
    die('There was a problem [' . $con->connect_error . ']');
    }
}

//create the function that will download a csv file from a mysqli query

public function downloadCsv(){

$count = 0;
$header = "";
$data = "";
//query
$result = $this->con->query("SELECT * FROM Your_TableName");
//count fields
$count = $result->field_count;
//columns names
$names = $result->fetch_fields();
//put column names into header
foreach($names as $value) {
    $header .= $value->name.";";
    }
}
//put rows from your query
while($row = $result->fetch_row())  {
    $line = '';
    foreach($row as $value)       {
        if(!isset($value) || $value == "")  {
            $value = ";"; //in this case, ";" separates columns
    } else {
            $value = str_replace('"', '""', $value);
            $value = '"' . $value . '"' . ";"; //if you change the separator before, change this ";" too
        }
        $line .= $value;
    } //end foreach
    $data .= trim($line)."\n";
} //end while
//avoiding problems with data that includes "\r"
$data = str_replace("\r", "", $data);
//if empty query
if ($data == "") {
    $data = "\nno matching records found\n";
}
$count = $result->field_count;

//Download csv file
header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=FILENAME.csv");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
echo $header."\n".$data."\n";

}
?>
```

After creating the "class.php" file, in this example, use that function on "download.php" file:

```
<?php
//call the "class.php" file
require_once 'class.php';
//instantiate DB class
$export = new DB();
//call function
$export->downloadCsv();
?>
```

After download, open the file with MS Excel.

I hope this help you, I think I wrote it well, I didn't feel comfortable with the text and code field.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternate and much sipmler solution, you can try this, i am using it for a few years by now, and never had a problem with it.

db_connect.php

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli($mysqli_host, $mysqli_user, $mysqli_pass, $mysqli_db);
if ($mysqli->connect_errno)
    {
    $debug = $debug.'<br/>Failed to connect to MySQL: (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') ' . $mysqli->connect_error;
    }
else
    {
    $debug = $debug.'<br/>Connected to '. $mysqli->host_info;
    }
?>
```

Export function

```
function export($query_exp,$name)
    {
    require '../lib/db_config.php';
    require '../lib/db_connect.php';

    $filename = $name.' - '.date('Y.m.d').'.xls'; /*set desired output file name here*/

    function cleanData(&$str)
                {
                    $str = preg_replace("/\t/", "\\t", $str);
                    $str = preg_replace("/\r?\n/", "\\n", $str);
                    if(strstr($str, '"')) $str = '"' . str_replace('"', '""', $str) . '"';
                    if ($str=='') {$str='-';}
                }

    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"");
    header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");

    $flag = false;

    if ($result = $mysqli->query($query_exp))
            {
            if ($result->num_rows>0)
                {
                $result->data_seek(0);
                while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
                    {
                    if(!$flag)
                        {
                        print implode("\t", array_keys($row)) . "\r\n";
                        $flag = true;
                        }
                    array_walk($row, 'cleanData');
                    print implode("\t", array_values($row)) . "\r\n";
                    }
                }
            else { $debug = $debug.'<br/>Empty result'; /*DEBUG*/ }
            }
    else { $debug = $debug.'<br/>Oups, Query error!<br/>Query: '.$query_exp.'<br/>Error: '.$mysqli->error.'.'; /*DEBUG*/ }

    require '../lib/db_disconnect.php';
    }
```

You can call the function as:

```
export('SELECT * FROM SAMPLE WHERE 1;','desired_file_name.extension')
```