# How can I fix MySQL error #1064?

Tags: mysql, parsing, syntax, syntax-error, mysql-error-1064

When issuing a command to MySQL, I'm getting error #1064 "syntax error".

1. What does it mean?
2. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 144, accepted):

> ## TL;DR
>
> Error #1064 means that MySQL can't understand your command.  To fix it:
>
> - **Read the error message.**  It tells you *exactly where in your command* MySQL got confused.
> - **Examine your command.** If you use a programming language to create your command, use `echo`, `console.log()`, or its equivalent to show the *entire command* so you can see it.
> - **Check the manual.** By comparing against what MySQL *expected at that point*, the problem is often obvious.
> - **Check for reserved words.** If the error occurred on an object identifier, check that it isn't a reserved word (and, if it is, ensure that it's properly quoted).

1. ## Aaaagh!!  What does #1064 *mean*?

   Error messages may *look* like gobbledygook, but they're (often) incredibly informative and provide sufficient detail to pinpoint what went wrong.  By understanding exactly what MySQL is telling you, you can arm yourself to fix any problem of this sort in the future.

   As in many programs, MySQL errors are coded according to the *type* of problem that occurred.  [Error #1064](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/error-messages-server.html#error_er_parse_error) is a syntax error.

   - ### What is this "syntax" of which you speak?  Is it witchcraft?

     Whilst "syntax" is a word that many programmers only encounter in the context of computers, it is in fact borrowed from wider linguistics.  It refers to sentence structure: i.e. *the rules of grammar*; or, in other words, the rules that define what constitutes a *valid sentence* within the language.

     For example, the following English sentence contains a syntax error (because the indefinite article "a" must always precede a noun):

     > This sentence contains syntax error a.
   - ### What does that have to do with MySQL?

     Whenever one issues a command to a computer, one of the very first things that it must do is "parse" that command in order to make sense of it.  A "syntax error" means that the parser is unable to understand what is being asked because it does not constitute a valid command within the language: in other words, **the command violates the grammar of the programming language**.

     It's important to note that the computer must understand the command before it can do anything with it.  Because there is a syntax error, MySQL has no idea what one is after and therefore gives up *before it even looks at the database* and therefore the schema or table contents are not relevant.
2. ## How do I fix it?

   Obviously, one needs to determine how it is that the command violates MySQL's grammar.  This may sound pretty impenetrable, but MySQL is trying really hard to help us here.  All we need to do is…

   - ### Read the message!

     MySQL not only tells us *exactly* where the parser encountered the syntax error, but also makes a suggestion for fixing it.  For example, consider the following SQL command:

     ```sql
     UPDATE my_table WHERE id=101 SET name='foo'
     ```

     That command yields the following error message:

     > `ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE id=101 SET name='foo'' at line 1`

     MySQL is telling us that everything seemed fine up to the word `WHERE`, but then a problem was encountered.  In other words, it wasn't expecting to encounter `WHERE` at that point.

     Messages that say `...near '' at line...` simply mean that the end of command was encountered unexpectedly: that is, something else should appear before the command ends.
   - ### Examine the actual text of your command!

     Programmers often create SQL commands using a programming language. For example a php program might have a (wrong) line like this:

     ```sql
     $result = $mysqli->query("UPDATE " . $tablename ."SET name='foo' WHERE id=101");
     ```

     If you write this this in two lines

     ```sql
     $query = "UPDATE " . $tablename ."SET name='foo' WHERE id=101"
     $result = $mysqli->query($query);
     ```

     then you can add `echo $query;` or `var_dump($query)` to see that the query actually says

     ```sql
     UPDATE userSET name='foo' WHERE id=101
     ```

     Often you'll see your error immediately and be able to fix it.
   - ### Obey orders!

     MySQL is also recommending that we "*check the manual that corresponds to our MySQL version for the right syntax to use*".  Let's do that.

     I'm using MySQL v5.6, so I'll turn to [that version's manual entry for an `UPDATE` command](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/update.html).  The very first thing on the page is the command's grammar (this is true for every command):

     ```sql
     UPDATE [LOW_PRIORITY] [IGNORE] table_reference
         SET col_name1={expr1|DEFAULT} [, col_name2={expr2|DEFAULT}] ...
         [WHERE where_condition]
         [ORDER BY ...]
         [LIMIT row_count]
     ```

     The manual explains how to interpret this syntax under [Typographical and Syntax Conventions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/manual-conventions.html), but for our purposes it's enough to recognise that: clauses contained within square brackets `[` and `]` are optional; vertical bars `|` indicate alternatives; and ellipses `...` denote either an omission for brevity, or that the preceding clause may be repeated.

     We already know that the parser believed everything in our command was okay prior to the `WHERE` keyword, or in other words up to and including the table reference.  Looking at the grammar, we see that ***`table_reference`*** must be followed by the `SET` keyword: whereas in our command it was actually followed by the `WHERE` keyword.  This explains why the parser reports that a problem was encountered at that point.

   ### A note of reservation

   Of course, this was a simple example.  However, by following the two steps outlined above (i.e. observing *exactly where in the command* the parser found the grammar to be violated and comparing against the manual's description of *what was expected at that point*), virtually every syntax error can be readily identified.

   I say "virtually all", because there's a small class of problems that aren't quite so easy to spot—and that is where the parser believes that the language element encountered means one thing whereas you intend it to mean another.  Take the following example:

   ```sql
   UPDATE my_table SET where='foo'
   ```

   Again, the parser does not expect to encounter `WHERE` at this point and so will raise a similar syntax error—but you hadn't intended for that `where` to be an SQL keyword: you had intended for it to identify a column for updating!  However, as documented under [Schema Object Names](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/identifiers.html):

   > If an identifier contains special characters or is a reserved word, you *must* quote it whenever you refer to it. (Exception: A reserved word that follows a period in a qualified name must be an identifier, so it need not be quoted.)  Reserved words are listed at [Section 9.3, “Keywords and Reserved Words”](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/keywords.html).
   >
   > ```
   > [ deletia ]
   > ```
   >
   > The identifier quote character is the backtick (“`` ` ``”):
   >
   > ```sql
   > mysql> SELECT * FROM `select` WHERE `select`.id > 100;
   > ```
   >
   > If the [`ANSI_QUOTES`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_ansi_quotes) SQL mode is enabled, it is also permissible to quote identifiers within double quotation marks:
   >
   > ```sql
   > mysql> CREATE TABLE "test" (col INT);
   > ERROR 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax...
   > mysql> SET sql_mode='ANSI_QUOTES';
   > mysql> CREATE TABLE "test" (col INT);
   > Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
   > ```

Comment: Seems to be a bug only for the column key, must be reserved word,

I'll leave this unanswered - since I haven't solved it yet,

Comment: @hreinn1000: `KEY` is indeed a reserved word—it appears in the list to which my answer links, at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/reserved-words.html .  It’s not a bug, the behaviour is by design and well-documented.  What are you “leaving unanswered”?  This post already is a full and complete answer.

Comment: There is definitely a bug. Not that I don't appreciate your answer (albeit  a condescending tone) but for my case, there was an extra parenthesis in my code but the response said the error was on line 651 (out of 850) underneath an "L".

Answer (score 3):

It is late but will help others and ofcourse will save time :)
My query was working in MySQL 5.7 in local system but on live we have version MySQL 8  and query stop working.

Query:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM groups t
ORDER BY t.id DESC
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
```

Output in MySQL 8:

> Error in query (1064): Syntax error near 'groups t ORDER BY t.id DESC'
> at line ...

I came to know `groups` is reserved word so I have to wrap groups with `` quotes or change the table name to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

For my case, I was trying to execute procedure code in MySQL, and due to some issue with server in which Server can't figure out where to end the statement I was getting Error Code 1064. So I wrapped the procedure with custom DELIMITER and it worked fine.

For example, Before it was:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS getStats;
CREATE PROCEDURE `getStats` (param_id INT, param_offset INT, param_startDate datetime, param_endDate datetime)
BEGIN
    /*Procedure Code Here*/
END;
```

After putting DELIMITER it was like this:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS getStats;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `getStats` (param_id INT, param_offset INT, param_startDate datetime, param_endDate datetime)
BEGIN
    /*Procedure Code Here*/
END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: This is not an "issue". You _have_ to use a custom delimiter when entering a proc 'cuz it uses the same delimiter as regular commands.

Comment: That's what we call an issue. I think you are confusing the meaning of "issue" with "bug" which is not meant here.

Comment: The issue here is that the custom delimiter is not required in all environments and that results in problem when a script working fine in development environment does not work as expected in testing or production environment and generates error.