# trouble with inner join mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, join, inner-join

Trying to do a simple inner join, but can't seem to figure out what is going on. Code is:

```
SELECT *,
FROM flgop as fl
INNER JOIN newuniverse as new
ON fl.Voters_FirstName =new.FirstName
AND fl.Voters_LastName = new.Last 
AND fl.Residence_Addresses_Zip = new.Zip;
```

Error message I am getting is:

```
[Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM flgop as fl
INNER JOIN newuniverse as new
ON fl.Voters_FirstName =new.Fir' at line 2
```

Comment: you have a comma after the * that needs to be removed

Comment: comma on the first line is invalid

Comment: thanks alot works now

Comment: You should accept the answer provided by @TomStudee

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I fix MySQL error #1064?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23515347/how-can-i-fix-mysql-error-1064)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *, <-- This comma is not necessary
FROM flgop as fl
INNER JOIN newuniverse as new
ON fl.Voters_FirstName =new.FirstName
AND fl.Voters_LastName = new.Last 
AND fl.Residence_Addresses_Zip = new.Zip;
```