# mysql error 1064, can you please see the code below

Tags: mysql

```
create table Employee(
     employeeID long(2) 
     , employeeName String(20)
     , joinDate Date
     , email String(50)
     , age int(2)
     , salary double(10)
     , address String(50)
)
```

Comment: `long` and `String` are not valid [data types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/data-types.html) in MySQL.  `DOUBLE` *is* a valid data type, but if you specify an optional precision then it must involve *two* parts.

Comment: read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23515347/how-can-i-fix-mysql-error-1064#answer-23515348 it's a very good answer from @eggyal

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
CREATE TABLE Employee
(
    employeeID double,
    employeeName varchar(20),
    joinDate Date,
    email varchar(50),
    age int(2),
    salary double,
    address varchar(50)
)
```