# Using split by tab in Python adds a character to text which raises error in MySQL

Tags: python, mysql

I want to read lines of a tab delimited file and split each line by tab. So here is the data:

```
File.txt:

524550170  {"text":He just proved he has no idea what he's talking about}  Sat Oct 31 15:40:00 2015
```

And here is my code:

```
con = mdb.connect('localhost', 'u', 'p', 'testdb');
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE user_profiles(user_id INT, json_source VARCHAR(1000), user_timestamp TIMESTAMP)")
with open('~/File.txt', 'r') as f:
    for row in f:
        data = row.split('\t')
        query="""insert into user_profiles (user_id, json_source, user_timestamp) values ('%s', '%s', '%s')""" %(data[0], data[1].encode('utf-8'), data[2])
        cur.execute(query)
```

But when I run the code and print the `data[1]` it adds a \ to "he's" part of the text and changes it to "he\'s". And when I want to add this into a MySQL table, it gives me a 1064 error, as following:

```
(1064, 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near \'s talking about.' at line 2')
```

Any idea what is wrong here?

Comment: How do you make/construct the query?

Comment: It's `\'` because the string is `'You have...near \'s talking about.'`(see the `''`). I think your SQL command is wrong.

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23515348/5299236) is what does *1064 error* mean.

Comment: Are there actually any tabs in that row? You didn't paste any into the question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are manually constructing the query via string formatting - this is not only dangerous in terms of security (you are becoming *vulnerable to SQL injections*), but also leads to problems like this.

Let your database driver worry about it and make a parameterized query:

```
query = """
    INSERT INTO user_profiles 
        (user_id, json_source, user_timestamp) 
    VALUES 
        (%s, %s, %s)
"""
cur.execute(query, (data[0], data[1].encode('utf-8'), data[2]))
```