# MySQL Error #1064 Link counter

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

I have been using [this](http://evolt.org/how_to_count_clicks_in_your_website/) site to build a simple link counter.

When I insert their code to create the columns, it won't work and displays the following error:

> error #1064.
>
> id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY_KEY, clicks INT

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Kindly paste your query here

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23515348/3181416

Answer (score 0):

Error 1064 means : "You have an error in your SQL syntax". 
It happens because

```
id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY_KEY, clicks INT
```

is not a valid SQL query at all. It's just the fields definition part.

To create your table, ensure you have a database selected and try:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `clickcount` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `click` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: I created the tables but they won't update the value.