# CAKEPHP: Error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I'm trying to read a row of my table using `read()` function and this gives me an error. I've tried to use `find('all')` but the same thing happens:

> `Error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax;`

Model Article.php

```
    class Article extends AppModel {

      function index() {

      }
    }
```

Controller ArticlesController.php

```
  class ArticlesController extends AppController {

    public $uses = array('Article', 'User');

    public function view() {
      $id = $this->request->params['id'];

      $this->Article->recursive = 3;
      $this->Article->id = $id;
      $articl = $this->Article->read();

      echo count($articl);
      exit;
    }

  }
```

Can anybody help me please?

Comment: that code is pretty much useless. show the bits where you're actually TRYING to use the db...

Comment: That controller should extend `Controller` **NOT** `AppModel`. Also, none of the code you've shown is relative to the error. Where's that code?

Comment: Sorry, I put the wrong code. Look now, please! @Ohgodwhy

Comment: Just to be clear - You've made a class called `AppController` which extends `Controller`, correct? And all of your other controllers now extend `AppController`?

Comment: where's the rest of that error? and where's the SQL?

Comment: *"Sorry, my english sucks."* - we can work with that. It's the "code" you didn't include and the rest of the error message that we are unable to work with.

Comment: Check out this SO answer may of any help:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/23515348/5632117

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
    $id = $this->request->params['id'];
```

is incorrect. However

```
    $id = $this->request->params['named']['id'];
```

will work if your calls look like `/articles/view/id:1`.

In CakePHP it's easier to use [Passed Arguments](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#passed-arguments). The parameters are extracted from the URL and passed on to the action. In your case:

```
class ArticlesController extends AppController {

    public $uses = array('Article', 'User');

    public function view($id) {

        //$this->Article->recursive = 3; // does not apply, only needed with Model->find
        $this->Article->id = $id;
        $article = $this->Article->read(); //will return a single row            
    }

}
```

By calling `/articles/view/1`, the `view` action will retrieve `id=1` from the `articles` table.