# getting error 1064 while importing data in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Usage: mysqldump [OPTIONS] database [tables] OR mysqldump [OPTIONS] --databa' at line 1

I am getting this error while importing my mysql database into phpmyadmin. What can be the reason?

Comment: show what you are trying to import

Comment: Please follow this link may you get some help form here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23515347/how-can-i-fix-mysql-error-1064

Comment: You seem to try to execute sg that is a comment within a dump file or an instruction on how to use mysqldump.

Answer (score 0):

This does not appear to be a valid export/dump/SQL file. If I had to guess, I'd say you redirected the output of `mysqldump` to a file, but used incorrect syntax when calling mysqldump, causing the error text to redirect to the file instead of the SQL code.

How big is your SQL file?

Try exporting again, being careful to monitor for errors this time. It seems to me you would have had to redirect stderr in this case, which is an odd thing to do, so you could also show us the command line statement you used to create the SQL file.