# I can't find cause error 1064 | MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-error-1064

I wrote SQL commands. MySQL says there's an error #1064 at line 36(line 36 is empty space/divider). I Know basic MySQL, but I can't find cause.

```
// TRENUTNI MOD REGISTRACIJE
$_hsync_rezultat = $_hsync_konekcija->query("SELECT Registracija FROM $_hsync_srv");
$_hsync_podatci = $_hsync_rezultat->fetch_assoc();
$_hsync_registracija = $_hsync_podatci["Registracija"];
// LINE 36
// NOVI ID KORISNIKA
$_hsync_rezultat = $_hsync_konekcija->query("SELECT Korisnika FROM $_hsync_srv");
$_hsync_podatci = $_hsync_rezultat->fetch_assoc();
$_hsync_id = $_hsync_podatci["Korisnika"] + 1;
$_hsync_od = 'From: haswell.samp@hotmail.com' . "\r\n";
```

Maybe error is here? $_hsync_usr is table name.

```
        $_hsync_konekcija->query("INSERT INTO $_hsync_usr (
    Ime,
    ID,
    Registriran,
    Zaporka,
    ZaporkaMD5,
    IP,
    GPCI,
    Mail,
    Spol,
    Godine,
    Skin,
    MailNotf,
    Datum,
    Vrijeme,
    Visina,
    OstalaMasa,
    MisicnaMasa,
    MasaSala,
    Zeludac,
    Metabolizam,
    PotrebaH2O,
    Opijanje,
    Drogiranje,
    Udarac,
    RastDlaka,
    hEx) VALUES (
    '$_hsync_ime',
    $_hsync_id,
    $_hsync_reg,
    'nista',
    '$_hsync_zaporka_hash',
    'nista',
    'nista',
    '$_hsync_mail',
    $_hsync_spol,
    $_hsync_godine,
    $_hsync_skin,
    $_hsync_mail_notf,
    '$_hsync_datum',
    '$_hsync_vrijeme',
    $_hsync_visina,
    $_hsync_omasa,
    $_hsync_mmasa,
    $_hsync_msala,
    $_hsync_zeludac,
    $_hsync_metabolizam,
    $_hsync_potrebah2o,
    $_hsync_opijanje,
    $_hsync_drogiranje,
    $_hsync_udarac,
    $_hsync_rastdlaka,
    $_hsync_hEx)");
```

I check it. I'm a bit confused.

Comment: `$_hsync_srv` is what, a string? Your question's unclear. and did you Google that error? Too many possible reasons.

Comment: `$_hsync_srv = "_HRP_SRV"`
It's table name.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23515347/how-can-i-fix-mysql-error-1064

Comment: That person who gave you that answer is giving you false information and did not put much effort into research. Plus, he didn't tell you "how" to use it. I've no idea why you accepted it. TBH, that `hex` had me thinking earlier, but I didn't have the time to "research" it (till now), and have spent the "time" to do it in their place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contrary to popular belief:

`hex` is not a MySQL reserved word.

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html

`HEX()` is a **function** used for Hexadecimal Literals

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/hexadecimal-literals.html

Additional reference http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html
*"Return a hexadecimal representation of a decimal or string value"*

You can use that word, but it needs to be wrapped in ticks *if it is required*.

Sidenote: But in this case it isn't since it is NOT used as a function.

For example:

```
RastDlaka,
`hEx`) VALUES (
'$_hsync_ime',
```

Plus, if you have any string values that are not quoted, then you will need to quote them just as you did for the other ones.

I.e.:

```
$_hsync_rastdlaka,
'$_hsync_hEx')");
```

---

Additionally, your present code is open to an [**SQL injection**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/). Use [`mysqli` with **prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO**](http://php.net/pdo) with [**prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements).

---

**Edit:** as far as what the real problem was:

> *Lol, problem was in input field, I used id instead value for radio buttons. Thanks! I'll check link for prepared statments. It looks a bit complicated. – SilvioCro"*

Note to OP: Please post all code relevant to a question's problem, it will leave out all the potential guesswork and others including myself, will be able (or at least help) find a full solution.

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// Then the rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Displaying errors should only be done in staging, and never production.

Also check for errors against queries:

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

It will help you during development as will [`var_dump()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) and looking at your HTML source (and your console if using JS/Ajax).

- ***Remember;*** the **more** we have to work with, the *less* time it takes to provide a solution.

Comment: Error is still here - http://i.imgur.com/pyc71bn.png
It's between Godine and MasaSala.

Comment: I echo whole query, and `$_hsync_spol` needs to be 0 or 1, but it's on(word on). Why?


Here's core for `$_hsync_spol` - `$_hsync_spol = $_POST['_hsync_spol'];`

 HTML part `<div class="btn-group _hsync_reg_sex" data-toggle="buttons">
           <label class="btn btn-default active">
             <input type="radio" name="_hsync_spol" id="0" autocomplete="off" checked> Muško
           </label>
           <label class="btn btn-default">
             <input type="radio" name="_hsync_spol" id="1" autocomplete="off"> Žensko
           </label>
         </div>
        </div>`

Comment: Lol, problem was in input field, I used id instead value for radio buttons. Thanks! I'll check link for prepared statments. It looks a bit complicated.

Comment: @SilvioCro ah, so there was an empty value going in the query then. I had a feeling about that from the beginning. I'm glad this was resolved to 100%, *cheers* and you're welcome.

Comment: @SilvioCro I noticed you unaccepted my answer and posted a new question http://stackoverflow.com/q/36966979/ why is that?

Comment: @SilvioCro I've made an edit to further outline how to debug code during development and have included your comment. This I feel has fulfilled the question's issues.

Answer (score 0):

hEx is reserved word in MySQL. So it gives error #1064, as query can't contain reserved works.

Comment: Thanks! So I need put hEx into [ and ] ?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html I don't see `hex` in there as being a MySQL reserved word. Why did you accept this answer? @SilvioCro `HEX()` is a function used for Hexadecimal Literals https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/hexadecimal-literals.html not a reserved word. Additional reference http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html *"Return a hexadecimal representation of a decimal or string value"*

Comment: I didn't knew that's a function. Thanks!