# Function bind_param() on a non-object | PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I edited my code with prepared statments(I didn't used them before). I get an error
"Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object". I googled that error and I found cause - error is caused if query has syntax error. I'm looking last 10 minutes in query and I can't find syntax error. Can somebody help me? Thanks!

```
// QUERY BEFORE
$_hsync_statment->bind_param("sisssss", $_hsync_ime, $_hsync_id, $_hsync_nista, $_hsync_nista, $_hsync_mail, $_hsync_datum, $_hsync_vrijeme);
if(!$_hsync_statment->execute()) $_hsync_reg_status = -1;

// POVEČAVA BROJ REGISTRIRANIH RAČUNA
$_hsync_statment = $_hsync_konekcija->prepare("UPDATE $_hsync_srv SET Clanova = ?");
$_hsync_statment->bind_param("i", $_hsync_id + 1); // THIS LINE
if(!$_hsync_statment->execute()) $_hsync_reg_status = -1;
```

I tried to close every statment after it gets executed. That doesn't help.

Comment: What is `$_hsync_srv`?

Comment: and you realize that you will be updating your entire db without a where clause

Comment: Show  how do you define $_hsync_statment

Comment: @Fred-ii-  There's No Time To Explain, Update Everything!

Comment: `$_hsync_srv` is table name(in variable). @Chris

Comment: @u_mulder *hehe*, sure... why not ;-)

Comment: @scaisEdge I don't understand You. I wrote $_hsync_statment = ....
`$_hsync_statment = $_hsync_konekcija->prepare("UPDATE $_hsync_srv SET Clanova = ?");`

Comment: @SilvioCro - we understand what `$_hsync_srv` is supposed to be, what we want to know is what the actual value is

Comment: @MarkBaker `$_hsync_srv = "_HRP_SRV";`

Comment: then add ticks `\`` around the variable. That leading underscore could be the culprit.

Comment: @SilvioCro then what is `_HRP_SRV` ?post complete relevant codes

Comment: @Fred-ii- Maybe I didn't understand what You say. It's a table with one row. Table contains settings. This is reason why query doesn't have `WHERE`

Comment: `$_hsync_statment = $_hsync_konekcija->prepare("UPDATE \`$_hsync_srv\` SET Clanova = ?");`

Comment: if you have more than one row, your entire table will be updated and so that's why I think is happening here. least, one of the things. and MySQL is complaining about that.

Comment: @FastSnail It's just a table name. I put table names into vars so later I can change table name easly(if I need to change table name)...

Comment: you have an answer now, ask him. I'm going to skp the question from hereon in.

Comment: @MarkBaker Still nothing. Query before doesn't have ` and it Works.
` $_hsync_statment = $_hsync_konekcija->prepare("INSERT INTO $_hsync_srv_sgnups (
 Ime,
 ID,
 IP,
 GPCI,
 Mail,
 Datum,
 Vrijeme) VALUES (
 ?,
 ?,
 ?,
 ?,
 ?,
 ?,
 ?)");`

Comment: again; the missing WHERE clause is a major contributor here. Plus now you pop in an INSERT that isn't even part of your original question, and the fact that you unaccepted my answer in your previous question is preventing me from helping you any further. So again; why did you unaccept my previous answer? You never answered me.

Comment: @Fred-ii- If You help for vote and other stuff on Stackoverflow, then don't help, please. Why I didn't accepted Your answer? Because problem wasn't in hEx, maybe MySQL looks different on hEx and HEX? Problem was in radio buttons. I didn't accept Your answer because maybe someone will have same problem like me, and he will find(maybe) my question with Your accepted anwser - he will try to do what You wrote there, and that won't work. Understand Know?
If You'll sleep better, I'll accept Your answer.

Comment: @SilvioCro Leaving me in the dark didn't help here. So, if you wanted me or expected me to add that in my answer, you could have given me that courtesy. Anyway, do what you wish; the question was solved either way. I offer help to provide a solution and that's all I can do and to outline errors in questions, code and from other answers given. I am after all, only human, *remember that* and we "all" all ;-) This stuff isn't embedded in our DNA from the day we were born. It's code, not blood. P.s.: When you post a question, don't leave out the important tid bits that you feel being irrelevant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So what's wrong with

```
$_hsync_statment->bind_param("i", $_hsync_id + 1); // THIS LINE
```

The fact that $_hsync_id is a variable that holds an int. when you add 1 to int. It produces an int that's not acceptable to bind_param. bind_param expects an object. Try this:

```
$_hsplus = $_hsync_id + 1;
$_hsync_statment->bind_param("i", $_hsplus); // THIS LINE
```

So now why did I get two downvotes when the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) clealy says:

> Note that mysqli_stmt_bind_param() requires parameters to be passed by
>   reference, whereas

Comment: I don't understand the downvoters. You have a point and my vote.

Comment: I tried that First. I don't think PHP is stupid language so he can't add up var with one.

Comment: @SilvioCro: It is about the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) saying *"Binds variables..."*. An expression is *not* a variable.

Comment: thank you @trincot. I dont' understand the down vote either.

Comment: Thanks. I fixed problem(wrong field name in table). After that I got this error. Thanks again!

Comment: had you checked for errors @SilvioCro would have avoided this question entirely.

Answer (score 2):

The error message Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object... means that you haven't properly instantiated the object $_hsync_statment before calling bind_params() on it.
have intiated the db connection to the $_hsync_statment 
    $_hsync_statment = $db->stmt_init();

Comment: I have `$` before every var(connection, statment...).

Comment: I wrote wrong field name. Thanks!