# ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Tags: mysql, database

i am trying to anonymize some student form our moodle.i am using mysql skript.
and I get the error . Can someone kindly help me resolve this issue.

```
ANZ=`mysql -u $USER -p$PASSWD -h$HOST -D $DATABASE -e "SELECT count(id) FROM $TABLE WHERE deleted=1 and not lastname='anonym';" --skip-column-names -B;`;
```

if [ $((ANZ)) -gt 0 ]
  then
    mysql -u $USER -p$PASSWD -h$HOST -D $DATABASE -e "SELECT id, username FROM $TABLE WHERE deleted=1 and not lastname='anonym' and username like '%@%';" --skip-column-names -B > $FILE;
    cat $FILE | while read TMP

do

```
    UserID=${TMP%   *};
echo $UserID >> $RES_FILE;
echo "User $UserID wird anonymisiert...";
```

`mysql -u $USER -p$PASSWD -h$HOST -D $DATABASE -e "UPDATE $TABLE SET username='$A$UserID', email='a@nonym.de', firstname='$A', lastname='$A', icq='', skype='', yahoo='', aim='', msn='', phone1='', phone2='', institution='', department='', address='', city='', country='', url='', WHERE AND deleted =1 AND id=$UserID;"`;

```
    `mysql -u $USER -p$PASSWD -h$HOST -D $DATABASE -e "UPDATE mdl_message SET subject='Neue Mitteilung von anonym' WHERE useridfrom=$UserID;"`;
    `mysql -u $USER -p$PASSWD -h$HOST -D $DATABASE -e "UPDATE mdl_message_read SET subject='Neue Mitteilung von anonym' WHERE useridfrom=$UserID;"`;

    VNAME=`mysql -N -u $USER -p$PASSWD -h$HOST -D $DATABASE -e "SELECT firstname FROM $TABLE WHERE id=$UserID;"`;
    NNAME=`mysql -N -u $USER -p$PASSWD -h$HOST -D $DATABASE -e "SELECT lastname FROM $TABLE WHERE id=$UserID;"`;

     `mysql -u $USER -p$PASSWD -h$HOST -D $DATABASE -e "UPDATE mdl_event SET name='Meeting with your Student, anonym' WHERE name LIKE 'Meeting with your Student,%$VNAME $NNAME%';"`;
done
echo "Fertig!";
```

i have got this errors:
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'AND deleted =1 AND id=715' at line 1

ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'AND deleted =1 AND id=3478' at line 1.

please help me.i am new in SQL.

many thanks for your help.

Comment: remove the comma after `url=''`. Also an `AND` whithout and Argument on left side makes no sence

Comment: many thanks for your consideration .it helps.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I fix MySQL error #1064?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23515347/how-can-i-fix-mysql-error-1064)

Answer (score 1):

You have

```
WHERE AND deleted =1 AND id=$UserID;
```

It should be:

```
WHERE deleted =1 AND id=$UserID;
```

Without `AND` between `WHERE` and `deleted`

Comment: many thanks for your consideration .i change it but unfortunatly it doesn´t help.

Comment: Hi,yes.i got again ERROR.i put this line: 'mysql -u$USER -p$PASSWD -h$HOST -D $DATABASE -e "UPDATE $TABLE SET username="'$A$UserID'", email='a@nonym.de', firstname='$A', lastname='$A', icq='', skype='', yahoo='', aim='', msn='', phone1='', phone2='', institution='', department='', address='', city='', country='', url='' WHERE deleted=1 AND id='$UserID';"';    and i got this ERROR:ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'demo@XYZ.de.1456411291' at line 1

Comment: This is totally different case and I am pretty sure you ask about that in different topic. By quick view not `username="'$A$UserID'",` but `username='$A$UserID',`

Comment: i changed username="'$A$UserID'" to username='$A$UserID' but it does not help.

Comment: Which variable gives text `demo@XYZ.de.1456411291` ?

Comment: this one:ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'axel.focke@uni.de.1456411265' at line 1

Comment: I am asking about **variable**

Comment: you mean this one:temp: 715 axel.focke@uni.de.1456411265
User 715        axel.focke@uni.de.1456411265 wird anonymisiert...

Comment: I mean **variable**. In your code you have few variables like `$TABLE` or `$UserID` and more. I am asking which variable keeps text `demo@XYZ.de.1456411291`

Comment: i am so sorry for bothering you.one of our co-worker has written skript and he ist not more here.i put all the code above and unfortunatly i don't able to find your question because as you see there is no variable for  email='a@nonym.de'.please help me again.

Comment: I didn't say that this variable is for EMAIL. That's why I asked you to check every variable. Can you do that or can you know how to do that?

Comment: please tell me how can i do that.i don't know.

Comment: IT seems you run this command in linux console? If yes, then just do `echo $TABLE;` and do on each variable

Comment: i wrote  echo $UserID;
    3478 logtest1@uni.de.1441958493
yes i am using Centos.

Comment: Ok, lets try it in different way. echo whole query: `echo "UPDATE $TABLE SET username="'$A$UserID'", email='a@nonym.de', firstname='$A', lastname='$A', icq='', skype='', yahoo='', aim='', msn='', phone1='', phone2='', institution='', department='', address='', city='', country='', url='' WHERE deleted=1 AND id='$UserID';"'`

Comment: i did it 
Line 67: End of file while looking for `'' achieved.
Line 71: Syntax error: Unexpected end of file.

Comment: what file? I must do it in linux console not in file

Comment: Maybe you should add some comma at the end ;

Comment: i do it ............deleted=1 AND id='$UserID';"',     i put comma end of Line but the same error.

Comment: It is hard to help while I do not know how you run all of this.

Comment: i put code in skript.sh and i run it in linux.i wrote also in code DATABASE="XXXXXXX";  
DBUSER="XXXXXXX";
DBHOST="localhost";
TABLE="mdl_user";

Comment: Here in comments it is hard to see right code. Please go here: http://nospor.pl/kontakt.html - this is my contact form - and put there content of your .sh file and send to me. I will check it in normal editor and send you back what I want to run to check errors. Maybe it will help :)

Comment: I've sent you mail. Did you receive it?

Comment: For next generations I am tell you now what was the problem: UserId contained text like this '611 some@email.here' but there should be only ID and that generated other problems