# Delete using a subquery shows #1064 error

Tags: mysql, sql

This query shows #1064 error.

```
DELETE FROM product_price AS pp
WHERE pp.PRODUCT_ID IN (
    SELECT PRODUCT_ID
    FROM (
        SELECT P.PRODUCT_ID
        FROM product p
        WHERE p.PRODUCT_NAME='watch') t
)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23515347/how-can-i-fix-mysql-error-1064

Comment: What exactly error do you get?

Answer (score 0):

Use `JOIN` instead of subquery like this;)

```
DELETE pp FROM product_price AS pp
INNER JOIN product p ON pp.PRODUCT_ID = p.PRODUCT_ID AND p.PRODUCT_NAME='watch'
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the 't' doing there? Try without that, like this:

```
  DELETE FROM product_price AS pp
  WHERE pp.PRODUCT_ID IN (
      SELECT PRODUCT_ID
      FROM (
          SELECT P.PRODUCT_ID
          FROM product p
          WHERE p.PRODUCT_NAME='watch')
  )
```