# MySql Error Code: 1064

Tags: mysql

I can't find the error. can you help me?

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE ReadBalance (IN mes INT,IN anio INT) 
BEGIN

DECLARE rowid INT;
DECLARE entity INT;
DECLARE grupo VARCHAR(100);
DECLARE relacion INT;
DECLARE ini INT;
DECLARE fin INT;
DECLARE tipo INT;
DECLARE detalle INT;
DECLARE ctain INT;
DECLARE ctaen INT;
DECLARE debe DECIMAL(17,2);
DECLARE haber DECIMAL(17,2);
DECLARE saldo DECIMAL(17,2);
DECLARE done INT DEFAULT 0;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE Balance (
  rowid INT NOT NULL
  , entity TINYINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
  , grupo VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL 
  , relacion INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
  , ini INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
  , fin INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
  , tipo INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 1
  , detalle INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
  , ctain INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
  , ctaen INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
  , debe DECIMAL(12,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.00
  , haber DECIMAL(12,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.00
  , saldo DECIMAL(12,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.00
) ENGINE=MEMORY;

DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;

DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR 
SELECT
  g.`rowid`,
  g.`entity`,
  g.`grupo`,
  g.`fk_codagr_rel`,
  g.`fk_codagr_ini`,
  g.`fk_codagr_fin`,
  g.`tipo_edo_financiero`,
  g.`Detalle`,
  ctai.`cta`,
  ctae.`cta`
FROM
  `llx_contab_grupos` g 
  INNER JOIN `llx_contab_cat_ctas` ctai 
    ON ctai.`rowid` = g.`fk_codagr_ini` 
  INNER JOIN llx_contab_cat_ctas ctae 
    ON ctae.`rowid` = g.`fk_codagr_fin` ;



OPEN cur1;
read_loop: LOOP
FETCH cur1 INTO rowid, entity, grupo,relacion, ini,fin,tipo,detalle,ctain,ctaen;

    IF done =1THEN
        LEAVE read_loop;
    END IF;

    SELECT debe := SUM(d.`debe`), haber:= SUM(d.`haber`) FROM `llx_contab_polizasdet` d
    INNER JOIN llx_contab_polizas e ON e.`rowid` = d.`fk_poliza`
    WHERE e.`anio` = anio
    AND e.`mes` = mes
    AND d.`cuenta` >= ctain
    AND d.`cuenta` <= ctaen
    ;

    saldo = debe-haber;
INSERT INTO Balance (
  rowid,
  entity,
  grupo,
  relacion,
  ini,
  fin,
  tipo,
  detalle,
  ctain,
  ctaen,
  debe,
  haber,
  saldo
) 
VALUES
  (
    rowid,
    entity,
    grupo,
    relacion,
    ini,
    fin,
    tipo,
    detalle,
    ctain,
    ctaen,
    debe,
    haber,
    saldo
  ) ;



END LOOP read_loop;
CLOSE cur1;

SELECT * FROM Balance;

END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

error message:

1 queries executed, 0 success, 1 errors, 0 warnings

Query:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ReadBalance (IN mes INT,IN anio INT) BEGIN DECLARE rowid INT; 
DECLARE entity INT; 
DECLARE grupo VARCHAR(100); D...
```

> Error Code: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done =
>   1;

```
DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR 
SE' at line 32

Execution Time : 0 sec
Transfer Time  : 0 sec
Total Time     : 0 sec
```

Comment: Maybe   ctai.`cta`,  ctae.`cta` in the cursor declaration need alias so the same name doesn't exist.

Comment: refer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/23515348/3682162

Answer (score 0):

I create this, and works correctly;

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `tindustrial`$$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `Cur`$$

CREATE DEFINER = `root` @`localhost` PROCEDURE `Cur` () 
BEGIN
  DECLARE rowid INT ;
  DECLARE entity INT ;
  DECLARE grupo VARCHAR (100) ;
  DECLARE relacion INT ;
  DECLARE ini INT ;
  DECLARE fin INT ;
  DECLARE tipo INT ;
  DECLARE detalle INT ;
  DECLARE ctain INT ;
  DECLARE ctaen INT ;
  DECLARE debe DECIMAL (17, 2) ;
  DECLARE haber DECIMAL (17, 2) ;
  DECLARE saldo DECIMAL (17, 2) ;
  DECLARE no_more_rows BOOLEAN ;
  DECLARE cur_B CURSOR FOR 
  SELECT 
    g.rowid,
    g.entity,
    g.grupo,
    g.fk_codagr_rel,
    g.fk_codagr_ini,
    g.fk_codagr_fin,
    g.tipo_edo_financiero,
    g.Detalle,
    ctai.cta,
    ctae.cta 
  FROM
    llx_contab_grupos g 
    INNER JOIN llx_contab_cat_ctas ctai 
      ON ctai.rowid = g.fk_codagr_ini 
    INNER JOIN llx_contab_cat_ctas ctae 
      ON ctae.rowid = g.fk_codagr_fin ;

  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET no_more_rows = 1 ;

  CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE Balance (
    rowid INT NOT NULL,
    entity TINYINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    grupo VARCHAR (150) NOT NULL,
    relacion INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    ini INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    fin INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    tipo INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
    detalle INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    ctain INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    ctaen INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    debe DECIMAL (12, 2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.0,
    haber DECIMAL (12, 2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.0,
    saldo DECIMAL (12, 2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.0
  ) ENGINE=MEMORY;

  OPEN cur_b ;
  the_loop :
  LOOP
    FETCH cur_B INTO rowid,
    entity,
    grupo,
    relacion,
    ini,
    fin,
    tipo,
    detalle,
    ctain,
    ctaen ;
    IF no_more_rows 
    THEN CLOSE cur_b ;
    LEAVE the_loop ;
    END IF ;
  END LOOP the_loop ;
  CLOSE cur_b ;
  TRUNCATE TABLE Balance ;
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```