# SQL SELECT foreign key reference not working

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a little problem with a SQL query.
I have two tables :

Table registrations

- ID, name, course (Foreign key to courses.ID), adress

Table courses

- ID, name

I want to select all values from registration and the name of the course which ID is in registrations table.

My query:

```
 SELECT courses.name, registrations.ID, registrations.name, registrations.course registrations.adress 
FROM registrations 
INNER JOIN courses 
ON courses.ID = registrations.course
```

Can anyone tell me, where my mistake is?

Thank you!!

Comment: Missing commas? Column aliases? Or what do you mean by "not working"?

Comment: The missing comma in my post is an typo, not in my code. When I try this query in phpmyadmin I get an error #1064

This is the exact query I use in my code and the columns are as described.

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23515347/how-can-i-fix-mysql-error-10640) for Error #1064.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue. 
The error was caused by an wrong configured conversion, courseID was text and was not parsed to integer (courses.ID) correctly. Thanks for your help.