# SQL Error :1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, prepared-statement

I have a Table called users like that:

```
    ____         ____            __________        _____________
   |    |       |     |          |         |       |           |
   | id |       | name|          |firstCon |       | secondCon |
   |____|       |_____|          |________ |       |___________|

     1           john               true               false

     2           mark               false              false
```

I want to change the `firstCon` and `secondCon` values with `true` or `false`.

So I'm using the following query:

```
$sql = "UPDATE users SET ? = ? WHERE name = ?";
$query->bind_param($condition, $value, $name);
```

Where `$condition` is either `firstCon` or `secondCon` , `$value` = `true/false` , `$name` is the name of the user.

I get that error:

```
1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version 
for the right syntax to use near '? = ? WHERE name = ?'
```

I'm using that method as I don't know which condition was selected , So I depend on the name.

Comment: You can't use a placeholder for a column identifier

Comment: any reason why you want to bind column names? Also FYI you can't do that

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I fix MySQL error #1064?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23515347/how-can-i-fix-mysql-error-1064)

Comment: @AkintundeOlawale , These condition values come from inputs , I don't know which one is clicked , I just know the name and the condition name then , So I can't just put a static column there as I don't know which one of them should be updated

Comment: its a bad idea to collect table and or column names via a form or any user-input. You should look for an alternative. Maybe you should also add your end goal to your question?

Comment: @AkintundeOlawale , My end goal is to update the table with the chosen condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot pass column names (or other identifiers) as parameters.  Here is an alternative method, that doesn't require munging the query string:

```
UPDATE users 
    SET firstcon = (case when ? = 'firstcon' then ? else firstcon end),
        secondcon = (case when ? = 'secondcon' then ? else secondcon end)
    WHERE name = ?;
```

Note:  This has more placeholders.  It might be simpler if you pass the parameters in as named parameters:

```
UPDATE users 
    SET firstcon = (case when :which = 'firstcon' then :value else firstcon end),
        secondcon = (case when :which = 'secondcon' then :value else secondcon end)
    WHERE name = :name;
```

Comment: I tried the first one and added a third condition , But it game me an error

Comment: and the second one gave me this error with 3 conditions :
`:which = 'firstcon' then :value else firstcon end),
      secondcon = (case when :which =' at line 2`

Comment: Thanks the problem is resolved , I used the first one, But there should be `end` at the end of the second check

Comment: `UPDATE users 
    SET firstcon = (case when ? = 'firstcon' then ? else firstcon end),
        secondcon = (case when ? = 'secondcon' then ? else secondcon end)
    WHERE name = ?`