# loop and select with stored MySql

Tags: mysql, while-loop, mariadb

I have the need to select the last enter for each Passcode for each department.
Each department has a 3 digit passcode, each person is given a code based on department. i.e. dept A has numbers 000-099, dept B has 100-199, dept C 201-299 and so on upto 999.

The database holds name and passcode for each person.
J smith      101
H frank      102
S saop       301
B Chesse     001
H roberts    401
K robert     402
b brety      403

I need a sorted that should loop over all results and return the last number from each dept (in the above case 102,301, 001, 403)

Not having a lot of joy, should be something like

```
    delimiter #

    BEGIN

    declare nmax int unsigned default 9;

    declare nmin int unsigned default 0;

    while nmin < nmax do

    select Passcode from main where Passcode < min*100 limit 1;

    set nmin = nmin+1;

    end while;

    END #

    delimiter ;
```

Just throws back 1064 error everytime?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I fix MySQL error #1064?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23515347/how-can-i-fix-mysql-error-1064)

Comment: no duplicate 1064 covers a load of error

Comment: could you please also share full error string?

Comment: Error: sql error (1064) syntax to use near 'BEGIN declare nmax int unsigned default 9; declare nmin in unsigned default 0 at line 8

Answer (score 0):

it seems you are missing "CREATE PROCEDURE" line here to me... Here my console output with similar declaration

```
MySQL [prime]> delimiter #
MySQL [prime]> CREATE PROCEDURE p1 ()
    -> BEGIN
    -> declare nmax int unsigned default 9;
    -> declare nmin int unsigned default 0;
    -> while nmin < nmax do
    -> select n from primes where n < n*100 limit 1;
    -> set nmin = nmin+1;
    -> end while;
-> END #
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.000 sec)

MySQL [prime]> call p1();
Empty set (0.000 sec)
Empty set (0.000 sec)
Empty set (0.000 sec)
Empty set (0.001 sec)
Empty set (0.001 sec)
Empty set (0.001 sec)
Empty set (0.001 sec)
Empty set (0.001 sec)
Empty set (0.001 sec)
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.001 sec)
```

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

After fixing the syntax error, you will find a couple more problems.

- What is `min`?
- In tanaydin's answer check the usage of `n`; it is messed up.
- `LIMIT` is useless without an `ORDER BY`
- `<` should be `>=`

This is a variant on "groupwise max", which has other solutions -- without any looping.