# error when run select query for datetime field

Tags: php, mysql

I got this error:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '=> "2018-08-14" AND createDate =< "2018-08-28" ORDER BY
>   createDate DESC LIMIT 0,' at line 1

When I run this query:

```
SELECT * FROM offer_request WHERE createDate => "2018-08-14" AND createDate =< "2018-08-28" ORDER BY createDate DESC LIMIT 0, 15
```

createDate is datetime field. i.e: 2018-07-19 12:53:59

Comment: it should be `>=` instead of `=>`

Comment: You are right. thanks

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I fix MySQL error #1064?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23515347/how-can-i-fix-mysql-error-1064)

Answer (score 0):

use date function to convert the createDate:

```
SELECT * FROM offer_request WHERE date(createDate) >= '2018-08-14' AND date(createDate) <= '2018-08-28' ORDER BY createDate DESC LIMIT 0, 15
```

Answer (score 0):

you have error in your sql query, must use like this and try to use date() function for datetime field

```
SELECT * FROM offer_request WHERE date(createDate) >= '2018-08-14' AND date(createDate) =< '2018-08-28' ORDER BY createDate DESC LIMIT 0, 15
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this Easiest and effective way :)

```
  SELECT * FROM offer_request WHERE createDate BETWEEN "2018-08-14" AND "2018-08-28" ORDER BY createDate DESC LIMIT 0, 15
```