# **When i execute this procedure than get error 1064**

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `GetStateList`(IN _CountryName VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN
    DECLARE @CCode VARCHAR(50)
SET @CCode = (SELECT CountryID  from countrylist where CountryName = _CountryName);
  SELECT @CCode;

END
```

Comment: You need to change the `DELIMITER` from semicolon to something else.  Check the documentation or a tutorial to see what the syntax should be.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I fix MySQL error #1064?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23515347/how-can-i-fix-mysql-error-1064)

Comment: Please see: [Why should I accept an answer when my query is resolved](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)

Answer (score 0):

You need to redefine the Delimiter to something else (eg: `$$`) other than `;`. At the end, reset the limiter back to `;`. Also, a semicolon was missing in the Declare statement:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `GetStateList`(IN _CountryName VARCHAR(255))

BEGIN
    DECLARE @CCode VARCHAR(50); -- semicolon was missing here
    SET @CCode = (SELECT CountryID  
                  from countrylist 
                  where CountryName = _CountryName);

    SELECT @CCode;

END$$

DELIMITER ;
```