# problem while creating a trigger in mysql error 1064?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a problem when creating trigger in mysql :

Error
SQL query:

```
CREATE TRIGGER product_after_insert
AFTER INSERT
   ON FRUITS FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN
      INSERT INTO products
   ( category,
     product_id)
   VALUES
   ( 'fruit',
     New.ID)
```

> MySQL said: Documentation
>   1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '' at line 11

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I fix MySQL error #1064?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23515347/how-can-i-fix-mysql-error-1064)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please find the fixed Trigger with inline comments about errors:

```
-- need to define DELIMITER to something else other than ;
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER product_after_insert
AFTER INSERT
   ON FRUITS FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN
      INSERT INTO products
      (category,
       product_id)
      VALUES
      ('fruit',
        New.ID); -- ; was missing for statement execution

END $$  -- End the Begin clause

DELIMITER ;  -- Redefine the delimiter back to ;
```