# Mysql error #1064 without a provided description of the error

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have the following `stored procedure` in `mysql`.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`cefcy`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `insert_eD_medication` (IN `p_id` INT(11), IN `strength` VARCHAR(45), IN `unit_id` INT(11), IN `package_no` VARCHAR(45), IN `medicinal_product_package` VARCHAR(45), IN `pharmaceutical_dose_form_id` INT(11), IN `brandName` VARCHAR(45), IN `route_of_administration_id` INT(11), IN `date_of_dispense` DATE, IN `substitution` VARCHAR(45), IN `stat` TINYINT(4), IN `v_id` INT(11))
    NO SQL
BEGIN
INSERT INTO `medication_dispensation_mapping` (`patient_id`, `strength`, `unit_id`, `package_no`, `medicinal_product_package`, `pharmaceutical_dose_form_id`,`brandName`, `route_of_administration_id`, `date_of_dispense_medicine_event`, `substitution`, `status`, `version_id`) 
VALUES (p_id, strength, unit_id, package_no, medicinal_product_package, pharmaceutical_dose_form_id, brandName, route_of_administration_id, date_of_dispense, substitution, stat, v_id);
END
```

When I'm trying to run it, I get the following error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 5
```

Can you help me please?

Comment: Have you tried defining a `DELIMITER` other than (default) `;` ?

Comment: @DanFromGermany No, the delimiter is `;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @DanFromGermany comment and the proposed [How can I fix MySQL error #1064?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43493692/1395874), I found the solution.

Even thought I haven't changed the delimiter I had to define it in the `stored procedure`.

Thus, my correct code is:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`cefcy`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `insert_eD_medication` (IN `p_id` INT(11), IN `strength` VARCHAR(45), IN `unit_id` INT(11), IN `package_no` VARCHAR(45), IN `medicinal_product_package` VARCHAR(45), IN `pharmaceutical_dose_form_id` INT(11), IN `brandName` VARCHAR(45), IN `route_of_administration_id` INT(11), IN `date_of_dispense` DATE, IN `substitution` VARCHAR(45), IN `stat` TINYINT(4), IN `v_id` INT(11))
    NO SQL
BEGIN
INSERT INTO `medication_dispensation_mapping` (`patient_id`, `strength`, `unit_id`, `package_no`, `medicinal_product_package`, `pharmaceutical_dose_form_id`,`brandName`, `route_of_administration_id`, `date_of_dispense_medicinal_event`, `substitution`, `status`, `version_id`) 
VALUES (p_id, strength, unit_id, package_no, medicinal_product_package, pharmaceutical_dose_form_id, brandName, route_of_administration_id, date_of_dispense, substitution, stat, v_id);
END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: I wasn't sure if you need a delimiter if you only have a single statement in the body but obv. one needs it..

Comment: You should review https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-programs-defining.html

Comment: @DanFromGermany You don't and in this case the begin..end counts as a statement - making 2 statements in the procedure. The begin..end are not necessary in this case since there is only an insert statement.