# How will i correct this SQL/MYSQL FULL Outer Join Problem?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
`SELECT leaderstbl.lfname AS leaders, IF(COUNT(vfname)>1,COUNT(vfname),0) AS followers, IF(COUNT(household)>1,COUNT(household),0) AS household FROM votersinfotbl WHERE vleaders IN (SELECT vleaders FROM votersinfotbl WHERE vaddress = 'ABACA') AND vleaders NOT IN ('NONE', 'none', 'None', '') AND vaddress = 'ABACA' AND household IN (SELECT vleaders FROM votersinfotbl WHERE vaddress = 'ABACA')

FULL OUTER JOIN leaderstbl ON votersinfotbl.lfname=leaderstbl.lfname
GROUP BY leaderstbl.lfname ORDER BY vleaders ASC`
```

**what seems to be the problem of my query sir?**

it displays this error:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'FULL OUTER JOIN leaderstbl ON
>   votersinfotbl.lfname=leaderstbl.lfname
>   GROUP BY l' at line 3

I am having trouble can someone help me?

PS: this is for my capstone
thanks everyone for your help!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796872/how-to-do-a-full-outer-join-in-mysql

Comment: Have you read the error message properly? Why do you use a `JOIN` after the `WHERE` clause?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I fix MySQL error #1064?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23515347/how-can-i-fix-mysql-error-1064)

Comment: Your code has multiple errors -- basically, it just makes no sense.  You should provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1):

mysql does not have full outer join, you can do left join two times or left and right join and union  which actually work as like full outer join

```
select col1..coln from table1 t1 left join table2 t2 on t1.col=t2.col
union
select col1..coln from table2 t2 left join table1 t1 on t1.col=t2.col
```

or

```
select col1..coln from table1 t1 left join table2 t2 on t1.col=t2.col
union
select col1..coln from table1 t1 right join table2 t2 on t1.col=t2.col
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using WHERE clause before FULL OUTER JOIN. Try this:

```
SELECT leaderstbl.lfname                             AS leaders,
       IF(COUNT(vfname) > 1, COUNT(vfname), 0)       AS followers,
       IF(COUNT(household) > 1, COUNT(household), 0) AS household
FROM votersinfotbl
FULL OUTER JOIN leaderstbl ON votersinfotbl.lfname=leaderstbl.lfname
WHERE vleaders IN (SELECT vleaders FROM votersinfotbl WHERE vaddress = 'ABACA')
  AND vleaders NOT IN ('NONE', 'none', 'None', '')
  AND vaddress = 'ABACA'
  AND household IN (SELECT vleaders FROM votersinfotbl WHERE vaddress = 'ABACA')
GROUP BY leaderstbl.lfname
ORDER BY vleaders ASC
```