# Getting error Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

I am new to MYSQL and I was trying to do an inner join but one of the columns is named TS%. It seems that the symbol at the end is causing this problem because when I remove this column it works just fine

SELECT Players.Player, Players.college, Seasons_Stats.Year, Seasons_Stats.Pos, Seasons_Stats.TS%
FROM Players
INNER JOIN Seasons_Stats on Players.Player = Seasons_Stats.Player;

Comment: What do you think `Seasons_Stats.TS%` is doing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I fix MySQL error #1064?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23515347/how-can-i-fix-mysql-error-1064)

Comment: Can you provide the full error, or is it just 1064?

Answer (score 0):

Use backquote should resolve that strange column name :

```
SELECT Players.Player, Players.college, Seasons_Stats.Year, Seasons_Stats.Pos, 
Seasons_Stats.`TS%` FROM Players INNER JOIN Seasons_Stats on Players.Player = Seasons_Stats.Player;
```

Because the `%` symbol in a MySQL syntax is used for some query operation.