# Creating table within mysql db, ERROR 1064 (42000)?

Tags: mysql

**Am working with MySQL 8.0 Command Line Client

I am trying to create a general table in mysql db but keep getting the following error:

> "ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AUTO_INCREMENT,
>   ManufacturerPTNO VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL, 
>   QuantityAvailable12am I' at line 2"

I have look through the manual but haven't found anything that helps with this issue; have also tried removing the index (id) column and assigning it as the KEY

```
CREATE TABLE quantity ( 
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    ManufacturerPTNO VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL, 
    QuantityAvailable12am INT, 
    QuantityAvailable01am INT, 
    PRIMARY KEY (ManufacturerPTNO),
    );
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I fix MySQL error #1064?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23515347/how-can-i-fix-mysql-error-1064)

Comment: `PRIMARY KEY (ManufacturerPTNO),` notice the extra comma i voteclose this as a simple typographical error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE quantity ( 
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    ManufacturerPTNO VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL, 
    QuantityAvailable12am INT, 
    QuantityAvailable01am INT, 
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
    );
```

Primary key should be `id`

Updated answer as per you comment

```
CREATE TABLE quantity ( 
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    ManufacturerPTNO VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL, 
    QuantityAvailable12am INT, 
    QuantityAvailable01am INT, 
    PRIMARY KEY (ManufacturerPTNO),
    UNIQUE KEY (id)
    );
```

Comment: Yes this works but I need the PTNO to be the primary key so connect to another table

Comment: Updated answer as per you comment

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: Appreciate if you accept the answer if it worked for you,

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE quantity ( 
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
ManufacturerPTNO VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL, 
QuantityAvailable12am INT, 
QuantityAvailable01am INT, 
PRIMARY KEY (ManufacturerPTNO),  <--- remove comma from here
);
```

and make PRIMARY KEY(id);

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error message, after a long time I realized that I was trying to create a table by name "order" and that was the problem.As soon as I changed the name it worked!!!