# MySQL null value not inserting

Tags: mysql

I have a query like

```
INSERT INTO support_users VALUES("1",,"2","1","4",,,"2017-05-06 20:24:36");
```

but new MySQL not inserting given error Error Code: 1064

but I changed it to

`INSERT INTO support_users VALUES("1","","2","1","4",,,"2017-05-06 20:24:36"`);

working

but previous MySQL not having such an issue.how to solve that. without changing query

table definition

```
CREATE TABLE support_users (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `client` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ticket` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `scope` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `notify` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `added` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=46 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: You already have an answer.

Comment: Could you show the table definition? I guess you have not null constrain at the column. Notice that empty string and null are different values in SQL.

Comment: i have more queries.is there way to change it .using variables

Comment: Which MySQL versions are you refering to? What is "previous MySQL"? And what are you using now?

Comment: @ Paul Spiege  new version 5.7.10  old version 5.6

Comment: **Your Solution is here-** [Error #1064 means that MySQL can't understand your command.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23515347/how-can-i-fix-mysql-error-1064)

Comment: Your query [doesn't work for me on MySQL 5.6](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/d9Ptb6vrCAbKD9VA32WWSF/0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## 1)

Integer column values should not be quoted.

So "1" becomes 1

## 2)

Auto Increment values should **not** be manally given to the SQL -- let it work it out itself.

## 3)

Inserting `NULL` using the `NULL` keyword.

## 4)

Your date-time column is set in its definition to show the current date-time of the row being inserted when it is inserted. As you are inserting (rather than updating, etc.) you therefore do not need to include this data.

## 5)

It is easier for your sanity to also list which columns are being added to with the INSERT instruction.

## 6)

Use single quotes `'` around string data **not** double quotes (`"`), when working directly with MySQL.

## Result:

```
INSERT INTO support_users( `id`, `ticket`, `scope` , `notify`)     
       VALUES (1, 2,1,4);
```

This will cause errors if you try to insert twice, because you are forcing the Primary Key (`id`) to be 1. To avoid this, skip the Auto Increment (`id`) column value.

---

*Or* for clarity **only**; the full SQL:

```
INSERT INTO support_users VALUES (1, NULL, 2, 1, 4, NULL, NULL, '2017-05-06 20:24:36');
```

Skipping the Auto Increment (`id`) column value (as referenced above):

```
INSERT INTO support_users VALUES (NULL, NULL, 2, 1, 4, NULL, NULL, '2017-05-06 20:24:36');
```

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, respect the Datatype. If its Integer don't use quotes.

The right way to approach your problem will be use of NULL. So this works across any version of MySQL.

```
INSERT INTO support_users VALUES(1,NULL,2,1,4,NULL,NULL,'2017-05-06 20:24:36');
```