# Why do I keep getting this eror: ERROR 1064 (42000)?

Tags: mysql, sql, create-table

I keep getting this error. What am I doing wrong? here is the code;

```
CREATE TABLE member(
    MEM_ID BIGINT(10) PRIMARY KEY 
);
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you share you query?

Comment: Try this: CREATE TABLE member(
     MEM_ID BIGINT(10) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(MEM_ID)
     );

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I fix MySQL error #1064?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23515347/how-can-i-fix-mysql-error-1064)

Comment: why You need BIGINT ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`member` is [a reserved word in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html). You need to either quote it with backticks, or better yet change the name of your table to something that is not reserved.

```
-- possible
CREATE TABLE `member`(MEM_ID BIGINT(10) PRIMARY KEY);

-- better
CREATE TABLE mymember(MEM_ID BIGINT(10) PRIMARY KEY);
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=eef110d6390fc346aac9dd1fb6f77e79)**

Comment: Thank you all. changed the name of the table and its working. Also incorporated your other suggestions. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

ERROR 1064 (42000) means syntax error. So something is wrong in the definition.

1. You could start by changing the table name to `members`.
2. Then declare the PRIMARY KEY attribute later in the definition.
3. Finally, the MEM_ID column should never be null, maybe be auto incremented, and unsigned as you'll never have negative values in it. NB: If you don't count on having billions of users, you can just use INT for this column. It will save you some space.

```
    CREATE TABLE members(
       MEM_ID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
       PRIMARY KEY(MEM_ID)
    );
```