# I see similar questions but still doesn't solve mine so my question is how do i solve the following error?

Tags: mysql

[code picture with an error #1064](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZnsWh.jpg)
SQL query:

```
CREATE TABLE `simzsy`.`membership` (

`memberid` INT NOT NULL ,
`name` TEXT NOT NULL ,
`surname` TEXT NOT NULL ,
`dateofbirth` DATE NOT NULL ,
`id` LONGTEXT NOT NULL ,
`contact` LONGTEXT NOT NULL ,
`datejoined` DATE NOT NULL ,
`membertype` ENUM NOT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY ( `memberid` )
) ENGINE = MYISAM
```

MySQL said: Documentation

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`memberid`)) ENGINE = MyISAM' at line 1

Comment: Have you looked [in the manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/enum.html) how to use the `ENUM` type?

Comment: You have to enumerate the posible values, like ENUM ('abc', 'xyz')

Comment: You are using an ancient version of MySQL

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I fix MySQL error #1064?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23515347/how-can-i-fix-mysql-error-1064)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query should look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `simzsy`.`membership` (

`memberid` INT NOT NULL ,
`name` TEXT NOT NULL ,
`surname` TEXT NOT NULL ,
`dateofbirth` DATE NOT NULL ,
`id` LONGTEXT NOT NULL ,
`contact` LONGTEXT NOT NULL ,
`datejoined` DATE NOT NULL ,
`membertype` ENUM('normal','admin','some_other_kind') default 'normal',
PRIMARY KEY ( `memberid` )
) ENGINE = MYISAM
```

So you enumerate all the possible values and set default value that is set if nothing is selected (instead of not null)