# Simple MySQL Update Query not working - mysql error 1064

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax, sql-update, mysql-workbench

I have a super simple query.

The query is:

`UPDATE tbl_name SET col_name = 'A934451' WHERE col_name ='B034451';`

Every time I run it the output is:

`mysql error 1064 – you have an error in your sql syntax`

In order to try to get it to work I have tried adding the schema to the start of the table, enclosing the column name in backtick's but with no luck.  The error appears at the end of the first col_name (before the equals sign).

(Note I have changed the table and column names but syntax is exactly the same - ie two words separated by an underscore).

I would really appreciate it if anyone can take the time to point me in the right direction. Fairly certain this is a case of not seeing the wood for the trees.

Comment: This can sometimes happen if you are not using the correct single quotes for the string.

Comment: what's your table schema?

Comment: Provide COMPLETE error message - do not cut off the tail. Also provide real SQL text and MySQL version.

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23515347/how-can-i-fix-mysql-error-1064 so you possibly find the error yourself and you understand why we need more information.