# Bulk Update query from Excel is not Working

Tags: mysql, excel

I am using a simple Bulk Update from excel (Cleanup & Trim - Done) into the SQL query as

update companiesdata set city='Kolkata' where ID=16;

When the same thing is copy pasted from excel, it is giving ERROR 1064, syntax error.

Whereas when i type the same it is not giving me any error.

What i want to achieve is multiple Updates.
UPDATE companiesdata SET CITY='Mumbai', STATE='Maharashtra', MARKETCAP=332791.24, INDUSTRY='Health Care' where ID=19;

What all settings do i need to check as i recently installed mysql Workbench.

FYI - Initially it asked me to remove SAFE MODE, that i did from Preferences too

Comment: What are the ''' (triple single quotes) for? Are they included in your SQL statements? Have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23515347/how-can-i-fix-mysql-error-1064)

Comment: Sorry, i thought codes hv to be written like that. Pls ignore the '''

Comment: Highlight the code and click the { } icon to put it in a code block. Your UPDATE statement looks correct, what is the rest of the error message. Can you also post a table CREATE statement, you can get that from workbench.