# SQL DROP query request

Tags: mysql, drop-table

I used DROP `ecommerce`.`users`; but it shows error #1064. Kindly help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I fix MySQL error #1064?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23515347/how-can-i-fix-mysql-error-1064)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to use:

```
DROP TABLE `ecommerce`.`users`;
```

Just `DROP` by itself is ambiguous. There are several different types of things you can drop in a MySQL database. Tables, indexes, triggers, views, procedures, or even a schema. You have to be specific. The word `TABLE` is necessary.

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/drop-table.html