# MySQL Event Syntax Error on updating some value where comparing dates

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create this event but I cannot find the syntax error.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE EVENT IF NOT EXISTS auto_decline
ON SCHEDULE
    EVERY 1 DAY
DO
    UPDATE Appointment SET status = 'Declined' WHERE deadline < CURDATE();
END; //
DELIMITER ;
```

so Basically I want my database to check every day that if the deadline (deadline is a column with `date` format) is already bigger than the current date. However my systems tells me there is a syntax error.
I also tried to use a IF THEN statement

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE EVENT IF NOT EXISTS auto_decline
ON SCHEDULE
    EVERY 1 DAY
DO
    IF deadlineToAccept BETWEEN offerSentTime AND CURDATE()
    THEN
    UPDATE PatientReceivedAppointment SET status = 'Declined';
END IF;
END; //
DELIMITER ;
```

[image]

still I got this syntax error. Notice that in my code there is no warning.[image]

Comment: Please show the actual error message in full

Comment: Have you tried [researching this error and the code that causes it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23515347/how-can-i-fix-mysql-error-1064)?

Comment: END; // try to remove the ;

Answer (score 1):

A function, event, trigger, or procedure usually has a body like `BEGIN ... END`.  When there is only one statement in the body, the BEGIN and END can be omitted.  Here, you have left out the BEGIN but left in the END; either remove the END or add a BEGIN.