# Error #1064 in MySQL when using MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I create a MySQL Model by MySQL Workbench. After that, I use the command 'Forward Engineer' and create the DDL script, but I have this error:

```
Executing SQL script in server
ERROR: Error 1064: 
SQL Code:
        -- -----------------------------------------------------
        -- Table `ClinicDB`.`TOATHUOC`
        -- -----------------------------------------------------
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ClinicDB`.`TOATHUOC` (
          `MaBS` VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL,
          `HoTenBS` NVARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
          `MaBN` VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL,
          `HoTenBN` NVARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
          `MaToa` VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL,
          `NgayKeToa` DATE NOT NULL,
          `LoiDan` NVARCHAR(100) NULL,
          `NgayHenTaiKham` DATE NULL,
          PRIMARY KEY (`MaBS`, `MaBN`, `MaToa`, `HoTenBS`, `HoTenBN`),
          INDEX `fk_TOATHUOC_BACSI1_idx` (`MaBS` ASC, `HoTenBS` ASC) VISIBLE,
          INDEX `fk_TOATHUOC_BENHNHAN1_idx` (`MaBN` ASC, `HoTenBN` ASC) VISIBLE,
          CONSTRAINT `fk_TOATHUOC_BACSI1`
            FOREIGN KEY (`MaBS` , `HoTenBS`)
            REFERENCES `ClinicDB`.`BACSI` (`MaBS` , `HoTenBS`)
            ON DELETE NO ACTION
            ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
          CONSTRAINT `fk_TOATHUOC_BENHNHAN1`
            FOREIGN KEY (`MaBN` , `HoTenBN`)
            REFERENCES `ClinicDB`.`BENHNHAN` (`MaBN` , `HoTenBN`)
            ON DELETE NO ACTION
            ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
        ENGINE = InnoDB
        KEY_BLOCK_SIZE = 2

SQL script execution finished: statements: 9 succeeded, 1 failed

Fetching back view definitions in final form.
Nothing to fetch
```

Please help me to fix this

Comment: What does `SELECT VERSION();` return? I will make a guess that you are using MariaDB instead of MySQL, MariaDB does not support the `VISIBLE` keyword. You can remove that keyword.

Comment: MySQL doesn't understand what you are telling it to do. I assume there is something wrong with the syntax. Is there no more details given? See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23515348/1921385. Also try https://www.piliapp.com/mysql-syntax-check/)

Comment: Also the `VISIBLE` keyword is not supported in MySQL 5.x so if you are trying to import a MySQL 8.0 table to an earlier version of MySQL, you should remove `VISIBLE`.

Comment: @Moob It's just that, no more details

Comment: `SELECT VERSION();` does not return anything? That's surprising.

Comment: @BillKarwin I removed all `VISIBLE` but now I have a new error "Error 1215: Unknown error 1215", and also have no more details

Comment: @BillKarwin it returns 5.7.34

Comment: Paste your syntax into an [online syntax checker](https://www.piliapp.com/mysql-syntax-check/)

Comment: Error 1215 is related to foreign keys. There are many thing that can be wrong about foreign keys. You might like this foreign key checklist: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4673775/20860

Comment: @Moob I paste that part of code into it and it says 'SQL looks fine'

Comment: @BillKarwin Thank you so much, sir