# Laravel 7 previous and next records with alphabetical order

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-7

In my edit form, I want to add a button to save and edit the following user.

I am trying that the "next" button takes me to the next record in alphabetical order.

I have only managed to order by ID

```
// In a model
public function next(){
  return User::where('id', '>', $this->id)->orderBy('nombre','asc')->first();
}
public  function previous(){
  return User::where('id', '<', $this->id)->orderBy('nombre','desc')->first();
}
```

Comment: Sort all and cache them in the frontend. DB server hits and sorting the entire dataset again just to get the next or previous one is too costly

Comment: Does changing your `where` clause to check for name > the name of the current record your editing work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the rank function of mysql and raw query

For previous record

```
\DB::select('SELECT * FROM (SELECT RANK() OVER (ORDER BY nombre ASC) ranking, users.* FROM `users`) user where ranking < {previous_record_rank} ORDER BY ranking asc limit 1;');
```

For next record

```
\DB::select('SELECT * FROM (SELECT RANK() OVER (ORDER BY nombre ASC) ranking, users.* FROM `users`) user where ranking > {previous_record_rank} ORDER BY ranking asc limit 1;');
```

And you need to set the mysql.strict to false in `config/database.php`

Or

```
\DB::statement("SET SQL_MODE=''");
```

Comment: Perfect, I did not know this function "rank"

Thanks!!

Comment: I'm using a shared hosting, and there does not work the statement statement

Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax

Any recommendation for this?

Comment: check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23515347/how-can-i-fix-mysql-error-1064