# how to get bulk insertion inserted id in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database, bulkinsert

I am trying to get insertedid after I insert multiple row in mysql table by using this query

```
insert into sometable (id , candidateid , createdby)
    values ('61','3175','1425'),('60','3175','1425'),('42','3175','1425'),('61','3176','1425'),('60','3176','1425'),('42','3176','1425') OUTPUT INSERTED.id
```

but I am getting sql syntax error

```
code: 'ER_PARSE_ERROR',
  errno: 1064,
  sqlMessage: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'OUTPUT INSERTED.id' at line 2",
  sqlState: '42000',
```

how can I get insertion id

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I fix MySQL error #1064?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23515347/how-can-i-fix-mysql-error-1064)

Comment: Mysql doesn't have this functionality. In your example you are inserting specific id's, so you have them already

Comment: you have an ` OUTPUT INSERTED.id` at the end remove it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `OUTPUT INSERTED` syntax is a [Microsoft SQL Server thing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16). That syntax is not supported by MySQL.

In your example, you have set the `id` values explicitly, so there's no need for them to be returned. Just get them from your own values which you apparently already knew before you did the INSERT.

You might be relying on auto-incremented id's, which are generated during the INSERT.

To get the auto-increment id of the most recently inserted row, use the [LAST_INSERT_ID() function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) in a separate query after your INSERT.

LAST_INSERT_ID() returns only the *first* id generated during your insert. If you do a multi-row insert, then it's up to you to extrapolate the subsequent id's. They are usually consecutive values. For example, the MySQL JDBC driver relies on them being consecutive values so it can return the set of id's after a batch insert.

But they are *not* guaranteed to be consecutive values if you have changed `innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=2` which allocates the auto-inc values in an "interleaved" manner, so concurrent inserts may grab a value from the sequence in between the set your multi-row insert is generating. This is not the default mode, so you would have set it deliberately.

Comment: The default setting is 2 (interleaved) as of MySQL 8.0, and 1 (consecutive) before that - [`innodb_autoinc_lock_mode`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_autoinc_lock_mode)

Comment: I wonder how they expect bulk inserts to be reliable then? I suppose the JDBC driver sets the mode back to traditional temporarily during a bulk insert.