# I need to create a null value in SQL

Tags: mysql

I am tasked to create a column with a null value but I got an error.

```
SELECT * FROM test.Persons
ALTER TABLE Persons
ADD mark_percentage FLOAT
```

This is my error.

> 12:32:47 use database test ALTER TABLE PERSONS ADD MARKS float SELECT * FROM test.Persons Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'database test ALTER TABLE PERSONS ADD MARKS float SELECT * FROM test.Persons' at line 1 0.063 sec

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I fix MySQL error #1064?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23515347/how-can-i-fix-mysql-error-1064)

Comment: those are two different commands. ALTER table doesn't return anything to select from, it just alters a table

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
ALTER TABLE Persons
ADD mark_percentage FLOAT
```